# Breaking out of nested loops with user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, nested-loops

Is there an efficient way to break out of a nested loop by having a user simply providing an input at the particular time they want to break out (e.g. press a key)? I have conditional statements in the loops themselves that I can use to break the loops, but if for example I simply want to stop the loops at any time yet still want the rest of the code to run, is there a simple way to do that? To clarify the motivation, I would like to do something like:

```
for x in xrange(1000):
    for y in xrange(1000):
        for z in xrange(1000):
            print x,y,z #function of loop
            if (user_has_pressed_key) == True: #a user input that 
                                               #can come at any time
                                               #but there should NOT be 
                                               #a prompt needed for each iteration to run
                break
        else:
            continue
        break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

I have considered using raw input, but would not want the loops to wait each iteration for the user as there will be numerous iterations. There appear to be some [proposed solutions when using different packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576960/python-infinite-while-loop-break-on-user-input), but even these seem to only be Windows-specific. I am running this code on multiple computers so would ideally want it to function on different OS.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the standard `signal` library for asynchronous events.

Comment: please provide a minimum working example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can break out of the nested loops if the user issues a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keystroke, since it throws a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception:

```
try:
    for x in xrange(1000):
        for y in xrange(1000):
            for z in xrange(1000):
                print x,y,z #function of loop

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopped nested loops")
```

Comment: This is essentially what I was looking for. But out of curiosity, is there a way to implement a similar method without the try/except statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the loop to break whenever **any** key is pressed by the user, then you can try this import:

```
from msvcrt import getch
while True:
    key = getch()
    if (key is not None): 
        break
```